# Formula needed to reference data from the last worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to figure out a formula to reference information in a specific cell of the last worksheet. The formula is for a summary sheet at the beginning of the workbook, referencing the same cell of the last worksheet in the workbook no matter the name of the worksheet. A new sheet is created every month, updated with the information and changes from the previous month. The worksheets are all labeled "Pay Estimate 1" and so forth.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&client=ubuntu&q=excel+worksheet+by+index

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy Excel worksheet and maintain relative cell reference in formulas](https://superuser.com/questions/397431/copy-excel-worksheet-and-maintain-relative-cell-reference-in-formulas)

Comment: All Worksheets in the same Workbook?

Comment: You just asked this same question a few days ago. You should delete this question and consider ways to improve the prior instance.

Comment: Please see item 1 of [expected behaviour](https://superuser.com/help/behavior). Also in the help, you can find [What should I do if no one answers my question](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers) and [How do I ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask), which may help get you moving in the right direction.